# How to position the recent interacted popper on top?

Tags: javascript, popper.js

I just started exploring popper. I am trying to use it to position popovers that users can interact with. The popover content can be as simple as a text and also a big custom widget. I tried a spike where I have the following:

Reference element 1 - Absolute position top 500px, left:200px . Has a popper with a custom widget big enough to have a scrollbar

Reference element 2 - Absolute position top 500px, left: 500px. Has a popper with simple text and a button.

Note: Reference element 2 appears first in the html.

Issue: The popper of ref elem 2 always appears below the popper of ref elem 1. I would like to bring the popper to top that the user is currently interacting with.

Questions:
Is there an api that will handle this positioning request?
If I have to manage the positioning, which lifecyle method or api should I be using?
Will managing z-index alone help?
Thanks!

I tried providing z-indices in a custom modifier but I dont think this is the right way since this is simply adding a property and not calculating anything with respect to the stacking context.

```
const topLogger = {
  name: 'topLogger',
  enabled: true,
  phase: 'main',
  fn ({ state }) {
    state.styles.zIndex = 100;
  }
};
```

In the picture, we can see the simpler popper hiding behind the bigger one. When I click on the simpler one, I would like to bring it to the top.